# How to ensure your MCU can't be reverse engineered?

Tags: microcontroller, mbed, security, encryption

I am building a project around an [nRF51822](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/nordic/download_resource/20339/13/33268213) chip from Nordic, using the mbed prototyping platform. I would like to ensure that the code cannot be extracted / deduced from the project after it has been programmed and released. Is there anything I can do, cryptographically or otherwise to make this possible?

Comment: Don't give it to anyone who has the capabilities to reverse engineer it...

Comment: There is no way to stop all reverse-engineering. You have to think about it in terms of economics -- you need to make it difficult enough so that the expense to the attacker is greater than the value (to him) of the code.

Comment: Don't design something that is fundamentally a big money maker because if you do then somebody will reverse engineer it even if they can't read your code.

Comment: OK, so are there any ways of raising the barrier of entry? The code-read example below from @DaveTweed looks a good start.

Comment: Dave left a comment to the answer by Austin but Dave is correct in what he commented. How will you stop someone is a problem not solved by protecting code. It's an inevitability if the product is good and can make someone money.

Comment: Ensured to what level of security? Casual user? The fbi? Quantum computers from the year 200&62?

Comment: Aren't all mbed projects open source by definition (and user license agreement)?

Comment: I am interested in any tricks to make this more difficult? @jippie this is only a project and the end result will be published, I just want to make sure once a device is released into the world, it is as protected as practically possible.

Comment: @Passerby I think ideally, a concerted effort with limited resources would be a great level. It is more just to help me understand the primary ways people might try to extract / reverse engineer code and methods to make that harder.

Comment: @jippie, no. The SDK is apache licensed, you can use it in commercial projects without open sourcing your own code.

Comment: @StephenPaulger I must have misunderstood, I thought all build tools were online only.

Comment: @jippie, you can use offline tools and even if you're using the online tools you can develop closed sourced software, software is only published if the user chooses to do so.

Answer (score 2):

On page 20 of the linked datasheet it says there is a "User Information Configuration Register" that can be used to disable reading the code off the chip. The datasheet doesn't say much more, you should be able to find more information in the programmer's manual or a similar document.

Comment: That may stop a casual attack done with limited resources, but it won't stop a determined attacker who has the necessary tools.